# Antlr4 c++ target looks like java

Tags: antlr4

I generated a c++ python parser with antlr4 c++ target but when I try to use it I have the following error:
Python3Lexer.h:48:5: error: stray ‘@’ in program

This Python3Lexer.h (generated with Antlr4 c++ target) does not look good?
The error line is @Override which is a java keyword, not c++!
Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Here is what this Python3Lexer.h looks like:

```
#include "antlr4-runtime.h"

class  Python3Lexer : public antlr4::Lexer {
public:
  (...)
  Python3Lexer(antlr4::CharStream *input);
  ~Python3Lexer();

    // A queue where extra tokens are pushed on (see the NEWLINE lexer rule).
    private java.util.LinkedList<Token> tokens = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
    // The stack that keeps track of the indentation level.
    private java.util.Stack<Integer> indents = new java.util.Stack<>();
    // The amount of opened braces, brackets and parenthesis.
    private int opened = 0;
    // The most recently produced token.
    private Token lastToken = null;
    @Override
    public void emit(Token t) {
      super.setToken(t);
      tokens.offer(t);
    }

    @Override
    public Token nextToken() {
(...)
```

Comment: Can you post your grammar and the exact ANTLR version you're using? That way others can (try to) reproduce what you see. If you're not using the latest version (4.7.2) try doing that first.

Comment: I am using v4.7.2 and Python3.g4 that I got from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python3

Comment: I'm getting old! I already thought the Java code looked familiar, I was the one who wrote it :)

Comment: A canonical is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)* (though should probably only be used for UTF-8 sequences. The lexer-induced ones should probably have their own canonical question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside the grammar file you're using (which you've linked in a comment), you'll see that it contains Java code. In order to use this grammar in C++, you'll first have to translate that Java code to C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is weird thant Antlr generates something wrong. Do you know if there is a way to find which target is supported by a grammar? Is the C++ conversion easy to do?

Comment: "It is weird thant Antlr generates something wrong", no ANTLR does not generate that code. That code is embedded in the Python3.g4 grammar.

Comment: @Guillaume ANTLR does not understand the code inside actions or know which language it's written in. It just inserts the code into the generated files exactly as it's written inside the actions. If a grammar contains no actions, it should work with all targets (though sometimes some targets don't immediately support new features). If it does contain actions, it will only work with the language that the actions are written in. To the best of my knowledge, there's no automated way to check this. You just look into the grammar file and check which language the actions are written in.

Comment: I understand what you both mean. IMHO defining the target in the grammar would make sense but that's another story. The Python3.g4 is not so big and I suppose the java code inside should not be complex so the c++ conversion would be straightforward, what do you think?